# How to Intercept Class Definitions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, interception

Is it possible to code something that can tell me when a Ruby class is defined?

Comment: Could you please tell us what you actually want from us?

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

```
class Object  
  def self.inherited(base)
    puts "#{base} inherited from object"
  end
end

class Animal
end

class Cat < Animal
end
```

Running the above code prints the following:

```
Animal inherited from object
Cat inherited from object
```

Basically, the `self.inherited` callback is triggered whenever a class is defined that inherits from the class it is defined on. Put it on `Object` and that's *any* class! (Although there may be some special case exceptions I can't think of just now).

I should probably add the disclaimer that, while it is possible to do this (because of just how awesome Ruby is as a language), whether it is advisable to do this, especially in code destined for production use, I'm not so sure. Well, actually, I am sure. It would be a bad idea.

Comment: Edit your top comment into your answer.